# Duplicate answer = duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

My question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433924/ie-shows-hidden-options-as-blank-fine-in-chrome-and-firefox) has been answered already as shown in the comments, but the question is not actually the same.

Does this still mean it should be considered a duplicate?

For clarity, my question is about a problem that occurs in IE but not in Chrome, the one linked to is about a problem that occurs in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: Does the linked answer actually resolve the problem?

Comment: Yes, the answer does indeed work for the question. Also I love that This (capital T) question seems to be a duplicate, except that the answer to the question it duplicates does not seem clear :(

Comment: @techturtle
Q1: What is the smallest primary number ? (A: 2), 
Q2: How many eyes has healthy human ? (A: 2)

 -- So Q2 is duplicate of Q1 (because answer for Q1 works also for Q2) ?

Comment: Following what is written by Jeff Atwood (co-founder) in point 3 on https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/ StackOverflow think it is interesting do have more questions for same answer but this seems to be not respected by moderator ! I take as example this question. I have found more quickly this question than original. That is proove for me that this question is better written than original. This is a heavy problem for StackOverflow. I'm interesting to have a survey on this in which reputation of user is taken into account.